# ActiveAdmin resource for a namespaced resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-engines

I am using ActiveAdmin for the first time. I am trying to create an administration page for a model that lives under my "Core" engine. I hence have defined a active_admin file as follows:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Core::Property do

end
```

This creates a tab within the active_admin tab section. However, I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/core_properties"} missing required keys: []
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks"

Answer (score 0):

Posted the issue on GitHub. Found a solution. Effectively, it was a namespace conflict with another engine.

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2394#issuecomment-22135350